# How to pass url to $stateChangeStart of ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use the following to redirect routes to login if a user is not logged in:

```
angular.module('app').run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$state', 'AuthService', 
    function($rootScope, $location, $state, AuthService) {

    /* redirect to login if not logged in */
    $rootScope.$on( '$stateChangeStart', 
        function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            if(toState.name === "login"){
               return; // already going to login 
            }

            if(!AuthService.user) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
                $state.go('login'); 
            }
        });
}]);
```

How can I pass the url from the "prevented" state to the login state so that I can continue navigating to that state once logged in?

Example:  User clicks link for myapp.com/#/path/to/data --> redirects to myapp.com/#/login --> user logs in --> user routed to myapp.com/#/path/to/data

I basically need /path/to/data to be sent to my login controller so that I can handle that.  I cannot seem to find '/path/to/data' in any of the state or param variables in the $stateChangeStart listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$state` service has an [`href`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) method which can create a URL given the state and its parameters. Since those are provided to the state change listener, you can create a URL and then pass it as a param to the login state.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
        function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            if (toState.name === "login") {
                return; // already going to login
            }

            if (!AuthService.user) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var redirectUrl = $state.href(toState.name, toParams);

                $state.go('login', {
                    redirect: redirectUrl
                });
            }
        });
```

You'll need to add a `redirect` parameter to your login state so you can use that.

Comment: this is giving me #/ for redirectUrl... however $location.path() mentioned by @mtadd evaluates to /path/to/data as desired.  I guess I will combine the two answers and pass the $location.path() as a param to the login controller.  Thanks!

Comment: What about moving the `redirectUrl` declaration before the `preventDefault()`?

Answer (score -2):

You can store the pre-login location in $rootScope, and then fetch it from there once login is successful

```
if(!AuthService.user) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $rootScope.pre_login_path = $location.path();
    $state.go('login'); 
}
```

And then after login, you can set the login path similarly in your login controller/service (have that include dependency injection of $rootScope and $location)

```
$location.path($rootScope.pre_login_path);
```

Comment: Services should be used to share data between components. Using `$rootScope` for that purpose is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I agree.  I'm merely using $rootScope as an associative array that's easy to inject into any angular provider for instructive purposes.  The risks with using $rootScope are the same for any global variables.